# How to set waitTimeout for RequireJS config in Aurelia CLI project?

Tags: requirejs, aurelia

I want to be able to modify the `waitTimeout` setting for RequireJS when used within an Aurelia CLI project.

Is there a standard way to modify RequireJS config in this context? Can it be done from `aurelia.json` directly, or a prepend script, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add config to the aurelia.json file, see the section in the Aurelia docs here http://aurelia.io/hub#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/11

Add a build.loader.config.waitSeconds key/value.

The exact example from the docs:

```
"build": {
    "loader": {
        "type": "require",
        "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
        "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
        "config": {
            "waitSeconds": 60
        }
    }
}
```